# How to generate square thumbnail of an image?

Tags: c#, .net, thumbnails

I want to create thumbnails of size 75x75 square from originals.
The thumbnail will not look stretched in one dimension as it will not follow the aspect ratio.

If have used Flickr, you will see they generate square thumbnails. I need the same thing.

Any clue or help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I am on .NET 4.0 C#

I am looking for programmatic way to generate thumbs. Batch capability needed if no dll available.

Comment: Add a tag for the language or technology you are using.  It seems you are possibly asking for a library to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is from [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/csharp/imageresize.asp):

```
static System.Drawing.Image FixedSize(System.Drawing.Image imgPhoto, int Width, int Height)
{
int sourceWidth = imgPhoto.Width;
int sourceHeight = imgPhoto.Height;
int sourceX = 0;
int sourceY = 0;
int destX = 0;
int destY = 0;

float nPercent = 0;
float nPercentW = 0;
float nPercentH = 0;

nPercentW = ((float)Width / (float)sourceWidth);
nPercentH = ((float)Height / (float)sourceHeight);
if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
{
    nPercent = nPercentH;
    destX = System.Convert.ToInt16((Width -
                  (sourceWidth * nPercent)) / 2);
}
else
{
    nPercent = nPercentW;
    destY = System.Convert.ToInt16((Height -
                  (sourceHeight * nPercent)) / 2);
}

int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap(Width, Height,
                  PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
bmPhoto.SetResolution(imgPhoto.HorizontalResolution,
                 imgPhoto.VerticalResolution);

Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);
grPhoto.Clear(Color.White);
grPhoto.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

grPhoto.DrawImage(imgPhoto,
    new Rectangle(destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight),
    new Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight),
    GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

grPhoto.Dispose();
return bmPhoto;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You can actually do this with MSPaint if you are on windows.